# Simple decreasing array confusion

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple little method in java that will create a list of decreasing integer values from whatever input I give it (So for example if N = 10, it will return an array of: {10,9,8,7,6,6,5,4,3,2,1}. This is a small part of my code and it compiles correctly, but I'm getting null pointer exceptions during runtime. Is there any issue that stands out in the code below?

```
private static Integer[] descendingIntegerArray(int N) {
    Integer[] a = new Integer[N];
    for(int i = N; i > 1; i--) {
        int q = 0;
        a[q] = i;
        q++;
    }
    return a;
}  `
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `q` at every iteration to `0`. Why not

```
private static Integer[] descendingIntegerArray(int N) {
   Integer[] a = new Integer[N];
   for(int i = N; i >= 1; i--) {
       a[i-1] = N - i + 1; 
   } 

   return a;
 }
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
 private static Integer[] descendingIntegerArray(int N) {
   Integer[] a = new Integer[N];
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       a[i] = N - i; 
   } 

   return a;
 }
```

Which is probably clearer

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be getting null pointer exception, your code has an index-out-of-range exception. This is because you run your `i` from `N` down to `1`, exclusive, while it should go from `N-1` down to `0`:

```
for(int i = N-1, q=0; i >= 0; i--, q++) {
    a[q] = i+1;
}
```

Note how `q` and `i` can be declared in the header of the loop.

You can rewrite this loop without `q` as well:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i != N ; i++) {
    a[q] = N-i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You repeatedly overwrite position `0` of your array by repeatedly redeclaring `q`. Here's the fix:

```
private static Integer[] descendingIntegerArray(int N) {
    Integer[] a = new Integer[N];
    int q = 0;
    for(int i = N; i > 1; i--) {
        a[q] = i;
        q++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

N is the upper bound. Arrays in java with size N are indexed from 0 to N-1. So when you refer to a[N], it will refer to an index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands now will return an array of size `N` but only the first element of the array will be updated ten times. Here's why as we go through the logic of your program,

```
create an array of type Integer, sized N
First iteration:
for-loop starts at i=N, let's make N = 10 for our purposes
q is set to 0 and a[0] is updated to N, which is 10 in the first iteration
q is incremented to 1
i is decremented to 9
Second iteration:
i is now 9
q is set to 0 and a[0] is set to 9
q is incremented to 1
i is decremented to 8
```

At this point we can see the problem. You may be thinking that `q` in the second iteration should start at 1 and be incremented to 2 after updating `a[1]` and not `a[0]`, but this is not the case. With each iteration of the for-loop a new variable `q` is made. After the iteration ends, the variable `q` is garbage collected/thrown out. Therefore, the solution is to use a variable that isn't thrown out after each iteration of the for-loop. So let's use `i` instead to access a specific index in the array since

1) the same variable `i` can be accessed with every iteration of the loop and

2) the variable `i` is automatically incremented or decremented at the end of each iteration depending on the loop header

So applying these changes will result in this,

```
private static Integer[] descendingIntegerArray(int N) {
    Integer[] a = new Integer[N];
    int q = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = N - i;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this :

```
public static Integer[] descendingIntegerArray(int N) {
      Integer[] a = new Integer[N];
      int q = 0;
      for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         a[q] = i + 1;
         q++;
      }
      return a;
}
```

You have to initialize q outside the for loop, because every time it loops, q is initialized with zero and it becomes a[0] = 10, a[0] = 9 and so on...